# Convert from Long to a Float Number

Tags: c#, types, floating-point, long-integer

In my Class I have a attribute, **fileSize**
The type is **long**

I don't want to change to float/double, cause I work with databases and now I can't just edit
the datatypes (to late)

the filesize is normally in **kB** (Reason why **long**)..
But once I want to show it in **MB** (that would be, **fileSize / 1024**) -> and I get *0*, its because the type isn't **float/double**..

How I can solve the problem, so that I get b.E 0.54MB without changing the DataType of **fileSize**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fileSize / 1024` performs integer division since both operands are integers. If you want to perform real division you could do this (at least one of the operands must be a real number):

```
double result = fileSize / 1024.0;
```

or:

```
double result = fileSize / 1024d;
```

Now result will contain the correct value that you want to print on the UI.

Comment: Yes.  You definitely don't need to change the DB field.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
double sizeMiB = fileSize / 1024.0
```

Or

```
string toDisplay = string.Format("Size is {0}MiB", fileSize/1024.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for example `fileSize / 1024.0` or `fileSize / 1024d`. [Both make the compiler treat this as a division based on `double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Divide by `1024.0` and the compiler will convert it to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
  double a = fileSize / 1024d;
```